# converting sql server file

Tags: sql-server

I installed VS11 beta and sql server denali. When I opened my web site, I was asked if I wanted to convert my database from format 665 to 771 (might have been different number, don't really remember). Unfortunately, I clicked yes.

Now I'm looking to deploy my site on the server and it runs sql server R2. How can I convert my mdf file back to sql server R2 version?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure you have a **backup** of that file somewhere in the "old" 2008 R2 format - right!?!?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, there is no downgrade-converting tools for exisitng databases. And you cannot backup the database on SQL Server 2012 and then resotre on SQL Server 2008 R2, because of error "backup is incorrectly formed".